# Camera.setPreviewCallback( PreviewCallback ) not working

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to get camera preview data, but I don't want to show the preview. Unfortunatelly

```
setPreviewCallback( PreviewCallback )
```

doesn't work unless you call

```
setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder)
```

Is it possible to pass this in any way - start callbacks without setting the preview display, or any way of hiding the display?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not the ideal solution, but you can try hiding the view that it is in. I made it to have a width and height of 1, so it is barely visible, but still is a valid SurfaceHolder for the call you need to make.

Answer (score 1):

Some devices will enforce the preview area being at least some minimum size. This means the 1 pixel preview won't always work.